# Extracting using awk in a specific column

Tags: awk

I have 4 fields and I want to start from last column and ignore the first 3 columns. How can I use NF in awk to do that?

```
root     pts/0        192.168.108.1    Mon Mar 19 08:45   still logged in
root     tty1                          Mon Mar 19 08:45   still logged in
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-693.el7.x Mon Mar 19 08:44 - 08:49  (00:04)
root     pts/0        192.168.108.1    Sun Mar 18 13:06 - crash  (19:37)
root     tty1                          Sun Mar 18 13:06 - crash  (19:38)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-693.el7.x Sun Mar 18 13:01 - 08:49  (19:47)
root     pts/2        192.168.108.1    Sat Mar 17 12:38 - 13:09  (00:31)
root     pts/1        192.168.108.1    Sat Mar 17 10:49 - down   (02:20)
root     pts/1        192.168.108.1    Fri Mar 16 23:17 - 00:30  (01:13)
root     pts/0        192.168.108.1    Fri Mar 16 21:25 - 12:56  (15:31)
root     tty1                          Fri Mar 16 21:25 - 13:09  (15:44)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-693.el7.x Fri Mar 16 21:04 - 13:09  (16:05)
root     pts/2        192.168.108.1    Fri Mar 16 08:45 - crash  (12:18)
root     tty1                          Fri Mar 16 08:45 - 17:25  (08:40)
syslog                                          **Never logged in**
```

I want to show only:

```
Sun Jan 19 13:52:08 -0800 2018
**Never logged in**
Fri Mar 16 08:45 - 17:25  (08:40)
Mon Mar 19 08:45   still logged in
```

Comment: If you use double space as delimiter you get the output you want: `awk -F'  ' '{ print $NF }'`

Comment: What *are* the delimiters? Tabs? If not, is there ever any whitespace in the first three columns?

Comment: `grep -oE '\b(Mon|Fri|Sat|Sun) +(Feb|Mar).+'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with a simple `awk` command to print the last column contents, and using a multiple spaces as the field separator. Since the default separator in `awk` is a single white-space, using it directly on the last column would split the contents of the last column. The `NR>` condition takes care of skipping the first line in applying the actual actions defined for `awk`.

```
awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' 'NR>1{print $NF}' file
```

or using `sed` too, assuming multiple spaces between columns and column separated words *only* in the last column.

```
sed '1d;s/^.*  //' file
```

---

OP apparently re-phrased the question to dump the output of the `last` column command from which they wanted the last column output. Since the intermediate columns themselves could have spaces, we do a match of the column containing the day name and print from there to the end of the line i.e.

```
last | awk ' {
     for( i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) {
         if ( $i ~ /Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun/ ) {
             j = 0
             str = ""
             for ( j=i; j<=NF;j++ ) {
                 str = ( str ? (str FS $j):$j )
             }
             print str
             break
         }
     }
 }'
```

Comment: @Cell-o: Is your columns separated by tabs or whitespaces? Can you post the output of `hexdump -c <input-file-name>` to the question

Comment: @Cell-o: See my update and see if it worked

Answer (score 0):

For the original version of the question, I had liked and up-voted Inian's answer, and deleted this one, but now that the question has changed....

```
awk 'NR>1{if ($2~/^\*\*/) $2=foo;if ($3!~/^[[:digit:].]+$/) $3=foo; $1=$2=$3="";print}' file
```

The `if` statements should place dummy values in the second and third columns if the second is `**Never` or if the third isn't an IP address, but will cause the answer to fail if other funky possibilities exist...

For readability, let's re-post the one-liner since it's a bit long...

```
awk 'NR > 1 {
  if ( $2 ~ /^\*\*/ ) $2=foo
  if ( $3 !~ /^[[:digit:].]+$/ ) $3=foo
  $1=$2=$3=""
  print }' file
```

Comment: @αғsнιη Quite right. It's fixable, but not without ruining its only advantage - fewer keystrokes.

Comment: I am getting `-bash: awk NR>1{if ($3!~/[[:digit:].]+/) $3=foo; $1=$2=$3="";print}: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Cell-o : You were too fast for me; I was still editing. Try the current version.

Comment: I assuming there is a small issue. when attempting run script then I am getting output like below.  3.10.0-229.el7.x Tue Sep 15 13:52 - 13:53  (00:01)
Tue Sep 15 13:51 - 13:51  (00:00)
Tue Sep 15 13:51 - 13:51  (00:00)
3.10.0-229.el7.x Tue Sep 15 13:46 - 13:51  (00:05)

Comment: I think script is not correctly catching.